# Apache Spark with Scala - Add rows from a matrix

Tags: scala, apache-spark, matrix, apache-spark-mllib

I have a CoordinateMatrix object in Scala. I would like to add, for instance, row 1 and row 2, and store the result in row 1. What is the optimal way to do that? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Let me help you to illustrate common ideas about it.

first of all, **the internal core data structure of CoordinateMatrix**:

`case class MatrixEntry(i: Long, j: Long, value: Double)`

the CoordinateMatrix is just a wrapper of **RDD[MatrixEntry]** with some easy to use interfaces.

so what you can do it with this class is:

**constructor**: `new CoordinateMatrix(entries: RDD[MatrixEntry])`

so you can use (and even rehashing) the merged rdd to provide a new contruction of it.

Comment: Yes, in fact I'm creating the matrix in that way. But the question is how I can add two rows and store the result in other row, something very close to an add or multiply operation when triangulating a matrix with gaussian method.